# Asp.Net Url Handling

Tags: asp.net, url, friendly-url

Is there a built in method to handle urls like Default.aspx/mycontent or do I need to handle it myself by taking the url and stripping of the file's path?

I have tried searching for it but haven't been able to find anything.

I'd like to handle .aspx/parameters and am not looking at Mod/URL Rewrite.

Comment: Not looking at mod-rewrite as its not easily available on shared web hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/). This framework obviously goes far beyond just "user-friendly" URLs, but it does also handle this as a byproduct.

Or you could just write a HttpFilter...

Comment: I have read about Asp.Net MVC but its difficult changing my development model altogether and switch to Asp.net MVC.

Comment: Understandable, whereas an HttpFilter makes it much easier, and can be completely transparent (though not completely trivial).

Answer (score 1):

You could either write an [url rewrite handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), use [ASP.NET MVC routing in your webforms application](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx), or use [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) instead of webforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you're app to do "friendly urls" then surely you would want to avoid ".aspx" appearing in the URL?  Have considered ASP.NET-MVC or at least the routing elements of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse out the appended "folder" using the Request.Url.Segments Array:

```
this.Response.Write(this.Request.Url.Segments[this.Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1]);
```

Then use Server.Transfer or render whatever you like. You will often have problems with relative paths and such for CSS and the like.